# MeteorJS: Collection.find fires multiple times instead of once

Tags: meteor

I have an app that when you select an industry from a drop down list a collection is updated where the attribute equals the selected industry.

JavaScript:

```
Template.selector.events({
  'click div.select-block ul.dropdown-menu li': function(e) {
    var selectedIndex = $(e.currentTarget).attr("rel");
    var val = $('select#industryPicker option:eq(' + selectedIndex + ')').attr('value');
    var oldVal = Session.get('currentIndustryOnet');

    if(val != oldVal) {
      Session.set('jobsLoaded', false);
      Session.set('currentIndustryOnet', val);

      Meteor.call('countByOnet', val, function(error, results){
        if(results > 0) {
          Session.set('jobsLoaded', true);
        } else {
          getJobsByIndustry(val);
        }
      });
    }
  }
});

var getJobsByIndustry = function(onet) {
  if(typeof(onet) === "undefined")
      alert("Must include an Onet code");

  var params = "onet=" + onet + "&cn=100&rs=1&re=500";
  return getJobs(params, onet);
}

var getJobs = function(params, onet) {
  Meteor.call('retrieveJobs', params, function(error, results){
    $('job', results.content).each(function(){
      var jvid = $(this).find('jvid').text();
      var job = Jobs.findOne({jvid: jvid});
      if(!job) {
        options = {}
        options.title = $(this).find('title').text();
        options.company = $(this).find('company').text();
        options.address = $(this).find('location').text();
        options.jvid = jvid;
        options.onet = onet;
        options.url = $(this).find('url').text();
        options.dateacquired = $(this).find('dateacquired').text();
        var id = createJob(options);
        console.log("Job Created: " + id);
      }
    });
    Session.set('jobsLoaded', true);
  });
}

Template.list.events({
  'click div.select-block ul.dropdown-menu li': function(e){
    var selectedIndex = $(e.currentTarget).attr("rel");
    var val = $('select#perPage option:eq(' + selectedIndex + ')').attr('value');
    var oldVal = Session.get('perPage');

    if(val != oldVal) {
      Session.set('perPage', val);
      Pagination.perPage(val);
    }
  }
});

Template.list.jobs = function() {
  var jobs;

  if(Session.get('currentIndustryOnet')) {
    jobs = Jobs.find({onet: Session.get('currentIndustryOnet')}).fetch();
    var addresses = _.chain(jobs)
                .countBy('address')
                .pairs()
                .sortBy(function(j) {return -j[1];})
                .map(function(j) {return j[0];})
                .first(100)
                .value();

    gmaps.clearMap();
    $.each(_.uniq(addresses), function(k, v){
      var addr = v.split(', ');

      Meteor.call('getCity', addr[0].toUpperCase(), addr[1], function(error, city){
        if(city) {
          var opts = {};
          opts.lng = city.loc[1];
          opts.lat = city.loc[0];
          opts.population = city.pop;
          gmaps.addMarker(opts);
        }
      });
    })

    return Pagination.collection(jobs);
  } else {
    jobs = Jobs.find()
    Session.set('jobCount', jobs.count());
    return Pagination.collection(jobs.fetch());
  }
}
```

In `Template.list.jobs` if you `console.log(addresses)`, it is called 4 different times. The browser console looks like this:

```
(2) 100
(2) 100
```

Any reason why this would fire multiple times?

Comment: There are two reasons the function may get called twice: 1. a reactive source under the function changes (maybe `currentIndurtryOnet` changes from `undefined` to `null`?) 2. The template gets re-rendered (something above or inside the templated is triggering re-renders?). Try a `console.log` in `Template.list.rendered` to investigate it further.

Answer (score 0):

As @musically_ut said it might be because of your session data.

Basically you must make the difference between reactive datasources and non reactive datasources.

Non reactive are standard javascript, nothing fancy.

The reactive ones however are monitored by Meteor and when one is updated (insert, update, delete, you name it), Meteor is going to execute again all parts which uses this datasource. Default reactive datasources are: collections and sessions. You can also create yours.

So when you update your session attribute, it is going to execute again all helper's methods which are using this datasource.

About the rendering, pages were rendered again in Meteor < 0.8, now with Blaze it is not the case anymore.

Here is a quick example for a better understanding:

The template first

```
<head>
  <title>test</title>
</head>

<body>
  {{> hello}}
</body>

<template name="hello">
    <h1>{{getSession}}</h1>
    <h1>{{getNonReactiveSession}}</h1>
    <h1>{{getCollection}}</h1>
    <input type="button" name="session" value="Session" />
    <input type="button" name="collection" value="Collection" />
</template>
```

And the client code

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {

  CollectionWhatever = new Meteor.Collection;

  Template.hello.events({
    'click input[name="session"]': function () {
        Session.set('date', new Date());
    },
    'click input[name="collection"]': function () {
        CollectionWhatever.insert({});
      }
  });

    Template.hello.getSession = function () {
        console.log('getSession');
        return Session.get('date');
    };

    Template.hello.getNonReactiveSession = function () {
        console.log('getNonReactiveSession');
        var sessionVal = null;
        new Deps.nonreactive(function () {
            sessionVal = Session.get('date');
        });
        return sessionVal;
    };

    Template.hello.getCollection = function () {
        console.log('getCollection');
        return CollectionWhatever.find().count();
    };

    Template.hello.rendered = function () {
        console.log('rendered');
    }
}
```

If you click on a button it is going to update a datasource and the helper method which is using this datasource will be executed again.

Except for the non reactive session, with `Deps.nonreactive` you can make Meteor ignore the updates.

Do not hesitate to add logs to your app!

You can read:

- [Reactivity](http://docs.meteor.com/#reactivity)
- [Dependencies](http://docs.meteor.com/#deps)